# Controlling Blender.osm with Python

Tags: python, blender

I have Blender and the add-on Blender.osm installed, and I'm trying to import a terrain programmatically from a Blender's Python script.

By hovering on the add-on GUI, I get these information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

which I try and implement as such:

import bpy
import csv
import math

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].blander_osm.dataType = 'terrain'
bpy.ops.blender_osm.import_data(0,10,0,10)
```

But the console shows some errors:

```
File "/Applications/blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 186, in __call__
C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
File "/Applications/blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 143, in _parse_args
raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported")
```

If it helps, here's the source code at the lines where the errors are raised:

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing I'm not proving the coordinates in the right format, but can't figure out how to do it properly... What's the proper way to import a terrain using this add-on?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you show is from the base operator class, it is generic for every operator in blender. Any args specific to an operator must be passed as named arguments. For the osm importer you will find the operator specific code within the addon. You should find the line `bl_idname="blender_osm.import_data"` at the top of the class definition of the operator.

To me it looks like most of the options will be set before calling as you have already done in the example you show. I doubt the import step will accept the location as an argument, it will be a case of import the model and then move it into position.

```
bpy.context.scene.blender_osm.dataType = 'terrain'
bpy.ops.blender_osm.import_data()
bpy.context.active_object.location = (0,10,0)
```

If the importer doesn't make the new object active, you may need to loop through `context.selected_objects` or get a list of objects before the import to find the new objects.

Using blenders [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html#auto-completion) should be the easy way to get the operators available arguments, using the consoles auto complete after the opening parenthesis will show the args you can use.

As I don't have the osm addon, I'll use the obj exporter as an example -

[image: Example of operator args from auto complete]